# Post Json data to ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

when you post data to elastic search . How does the mapping works on those fields and metadata? Do we have to define the mapping somewhere or elastic search does automatically when you index that data to elasticsearch. Any ideas around that will be appreciated as im new to elasticsearch.

Comment: When Elasticsearch encounters a previously unknown field in a document, it uses dynamic mapping to determine the datatype for the field and automatically adds the new field to the type mapping. [Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-mapping). Your question is a bit unclear to me. If you could reformulate I could help you more.

Comment: thanks for the information. yes thats the case of automatic detection in case of dynamic mapping. What if we want to do the same using static mapping where we define the mapping before indexing to elastic search. Where do we do the static mapping . Do we need any json mapping file?

Comment: This is how you create a mapping before indexing any data: [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For elasticsearch it is not necessary to define a mapping. It provides automatic mapping which detects the type of each field upon adding the first document.

For example by adding following document:

```
{
   "doc": {
       "user": "Max",
       "createdAt": "2016-04-12T23:00:00",
       "age": 20
   }
}
```

Elasticsearch triggers the following mapping:

```
{ 
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "user" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "createdAt" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"      
          },
          "age" : {
            "type" : "long"                    
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you prefer to define the structure of an index you can also provide mapping in json format before you add the documents.

For more information, check out this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapping.html